# For my ExtJS 4.2.2 app, what should I store in git when generating workspace/app/package?

Tags: git, extjs

I generated a workspace and an application using Sencha Cmd, which copies a subset of the ExtJS 4.2.2 SDK into the workspace, and creates a folder skeleton for the app.

I'm wondering what I should store in git, because the build system pulls from git for the latest code.

So I now have this folder structure:

```
/webapp
    /ext422
    /workspace
        /.sencha
        /build
        /ext
        /extApps
            /firstapp
        /packages
```

So a sub-set of ext422 SDK was copied to ext inside the workspace folder.

Which of these folders should be submitted to git, and which should be ignored by git?

Comment: I put it all in there personally but the only truly interesting folders would be the extApps and maybe the packages folder. The other ones are the gigantic Ext framework with all of its thousands of files which can be downloaded from Sencha.

Comment: The build machine will need to build the app, build the package, build themes, I assume. That's what leads me to believe much of it needs to be in git. Just not sure. Can we download extjs 4.2.2 to the build machine for each build, like from some public repository?

Comment: Version 4.2.2 is for Sencha support subscribers only but version 4.2.1 is published with GPL licence and available on many major CDNs . Sencha hosts it as well at cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/

Comment: Thinking about it more, whatever machine is going to build the workspace should have the whole workspace present and just let Sencha CMD do its magic. It can be kind of picky about not changing the basic generated folder structures and files

Comment: I store everything but the sass cache directory